# How do I name the Artifact Id in maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, installation, project

I wonder shall I name the Artifact Id freely? Or with the same name of Group Id
will it be trouble when I develop further?

I have seen examples on website giving a name like that
"java-web-crawler"

Comment: A library is identified by both group id and artifact id, name the artifact id freely as you want to.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html

Comment: @tianwei There is a third item for building a (unique) identification of an artifact: the version. All three together often called _GAV_.